# Reduction of a possibly non-integral element modulo an ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $K$ be a number field and $f(x) \in\mathcal{O}_{K}[x]$ with splitting field $L/K$. Suppose $\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}, \ldots, \theta_{k}$ be the roots of $f(x)$ in $L$, i.e., $f(x)  = \prod_{i=1}^{k} (x - \theta_{i})$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime in $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ and assume that for some $\alpha \in\mathcal{O}_{K}$, we have $f(\alpha) \equiv 0\hspace{1mm} (\text{mod } p)$. Now, since $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime, this seems to force that $(\alpha - \theta_{j}) \equiv 0 \hspace{1mm} (\text{mod } \mathfrak{p})$ for some $j \in\{1, 2, \ldots, k\}$, i.e., $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_{K} \mid (\theta_{j} - \alpha)\mathcal{O}_{K}$ as ideals in $\mathcal{O}_{K}$.

If $\mathfrak P$ is a prime in $\mathcal O_L$ above $\mathfrak{p}$, then $\mathfrak P\mathcal{O}_{L}\mid\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_{L}$ in $\mathcal{O}_{L}$. I wanted to arrive at the fact that $\mathfrak P\mathcal{O}_{L} \mid (\theta_{j} - \alpha)\mathcal{O}_{L}$ as ideals in $\mathcal{O}_{L}$.

**My attempt:**

I wanted to say that since $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_{K} \mid (\theta_{j} - \alpha)\mathcal{O}_{K}$, we have that $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_{L} \mid (\theta_{j} - \alpha)\mathcal{O}_{L}$, which combined with $\mathfrak P\mathcal{O}_{L}\mid\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_{L}$ gives what I want. However, I feel uneasy with such an argument for two reasons:

1. Is it always true that $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_{K} \mid \mathfrak{q}\mathcal{O}_{K}$ implies $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_{L} \mid \mathfrak{q}\mathcal{O}_{L}$? I think it is true but finding it hard to justify to myself.
2. Another question is that $\theta_{j}$ may not be integral in $L$. In this case, how can I say that $\mathfrak P\mathcal{O}_{L} \mid (\theta_{j} - \alpha)\mathcal{O}_{L}$ as ideals in $\mathcal{O}_{L}$? I feel like I have to explain something here too.

Any help on my argument and 2 counter-arguments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. The extension of ideals commutes with products.

Comment: @user26857 If I understand the language you have used, you mean to say that $(\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{q})\mathcal{O}_{L} = (\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_{L}) (\mathfrak{q}\mathcal{O}_{L})$ for two ideals $\mathfrak{p}, \mathfrak{q}$ in $\mathcal{O}_{K}$?  That would certainly answer my first concern. Thanks. Any hint for the second one?

Comment: If, as you seem to posit, $f$ is _monic_ with coefs in the base ring of integers, then its zeros, wherever they may be, are integral over that base ring... Am I not understanding your question?

Comment: @paulgarrett omg! I see.. I have made an error… thank you so much.. now i have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. I will adress your concerns.

1. Recall that $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_K \mid \mathfrak{q}\mathcal{O}_K=\mathfrak{q}$ just means that $\mathfrak{q}\subseteq \mathfrak{p}$. Then it is very easy to prove that $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_L \mid \mathfrak{q}\mathcal{O}_L$ by remembering how these products are defined. Indeed, let $\alpha\in\mathfrak{q}$. Then $\alpha\in\mathfrak{p}$ by assumption. Thus, for any $\beta\in \mathfrak{q}\mathcal{O}_L$, it has the form $\beta=\sum_i\alpha_i d_i$ for some $\alpha_i\in\mathfrak{q}$ and some $d_i\in\mathcal{O}_L$. Clearly each $\alpha_i d_i\in \mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_L$, and so the same holds for their sum.
2. For any field extension $L/K$, we have $\mathcal{O}_K\subset \mathcal{O}_L$, so $\theta_i$ must be integral in $L$. This inclusion is very easy to prove, and very fundamental.